# How to install multiple brother printers properly on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, brother-printer

I have installed the **complete driver and software suite** (translated from German) for an MFC-L3730CDN. It's working fine.

Now I want to install/add an MFC-J1010CDW.

I want to have all the original brother tools and functions which are already working for the MFC-L3730CDN:

- Control Center 4
- showing the ink level
- Brother iPrint & Scan

I am concerned to install the complete drive and software suite for the MFC-J1010CDW because I already have most of it installed. Perhaps I will end up having two different Control Center versions installed.

So how to do it properly?

Comment: Why don't you try adding the new printer *without/* installing anything else? Chances are it'll just work.